# Monospace font string width

Tags: javascript, html, css, width, monospace

I have an input element which feeds into a list element, both with the same monospace font. `char_width_test` is the ID of a `span` element that contains 1 character with the same monospace font. I check this width and 
multiply with the length of strings given in the input field to calculate the width of the list item that is created from that string.

```
var ul = document.getElementById('posts_list');
var li = document.createElement('li');
var txt = document.createTextNode(str);
ul.appendChild(li);
li.innerHTML = str;

li.style.width = (($("#char_width_test").width() * str.length)) + 'px';
```

Above code produces widths that have more whitespace the longer the strings. There seems to be some variable affecting the width that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

There is kerning between characters, so the width of one character isn't quite what you want to multiply.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning

Once you've determined the width of one letter and the amount of kerning, you'll need `n * char_width + (n - 1) * kerning_width` to be more accurate.

I might try something like `kerning = width_of_two_characters - (width_of_one_character * 2)` if there is no padding or margin on the span. See how that works out.

Comment: Seems like a nice solution, however I'm getting width_of_two_chars = 20 and width_of_one_char = 10